# I wants to give a animation effect on hover with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a button

I wants to give button an animation effect that it will show right arrow when gets hovered. You can find example here (Just any button with right arrow appearing on animation )  http://demo.simpleprothemes.com/flex/magazine/?fbclid=IwAR1J-_tRUdOMOrKsOMtTuYdgVR4vJqEfjLAMva93G7CxjvcEhhuNsqqHZzw

I have tried giving it animation with jquery but it didn't turned out as expected.

```
$(function() {
  $('.hover_right_arrow').hover(

    function() {
      $(this).append($("  <span class='right_arrow'> &nbsp > </span>"));
      $('.right_arrow').fadeToggle(2000);
    },
    function() {
      $(this).find('span:last').remove();
    }
  );

  $('.hover_right_arrow').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).fadeToggle(600);
      // $(this).fadeIn(2600);
    }

  );
});
```

You can see my demo at https://mahd.webonspeed.com/signin.php

How to achieve the animation on given website?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is with CSS. The styles bellow are just and example. Hope this helps.

```
button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
button::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 4px;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  display: none;
}
button:hover::after {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made it work but with no animation.

```
    .my_hover_right_arrow:hover::after {
        content: '>';
        margin-left: 4px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: medium;
        transition: 1s;
    }
```